# In ionic framework error while add platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

error while running $ cordova platform add android error shows like as follows.And
changing cordova android versions is affected to other installed plugins.

**Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.0.0, failed version requirement:      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sarath/Desktop/My_Files/Bravo_codes/Projects/omasouq-app/omasouq-app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (/home/sarath/Desktop/My_Files/Bravo_codes/Projects/omasouq-app/omasouq-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/util/xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (/home/sarath/Desktop/My_Files/Bravo_codes/Projects/omasouq-app/omasouq-app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (/home/sarath/Desktop/My_Files/Bravo_codes/Projects/omasouq-app/omasouq-app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin (/home/sarath/Desktop/My_Files/Bravo_codes/Projects/omasouq-app/omasouq-app/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (/home/sarath/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:594:10)
    at /home/sarath/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (/home/sarath/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/sarath/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your install plugin first then upgrade cordova platform.

Or

You can remove all plugins first then upgrade your cordova android version and after that again reinstall all your plugins.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-compat#deprecated Now i think there is no more need of "cordova-plugin-compat" in your apps.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade cordova platform `ionic cordova add platform android@6.4.0`

Comment: its affect other plugins. have any way to update version requirement:
      <6.3.0